# Is there a way to make AM/PM as a required in owl-date-time picker?

Tags: angular, angular6, datetimepicker

I am using owl-date-time picker for the time picker in angular.
I have taken this as a reference - https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/  . My requirement is

1) While selecting the time i want to make the Am/Pm mandatory, without selecting that we should not click the set button.

2) (If above requirement is not possible then) After selecting the time i want to disable the am/pm in the input field.

Here you can refer the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-datetimepicker

### Timer Only

```
<label class="example-input-wrapper">
    Time:
    <input placeholder="Time:"
           [(ngModel)]="dateTime2"
           [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2" [owlDateTime]="dt2">
    <owl-date-time hour12Timer="true" [pickerType]="'timer'" #dt2></owl-date-time>
</label>
```

Here is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg3g8.jpg

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this by applying css.

You can apply `class` when the time has been selected by the user.

```
:host ::ng-deep owl-dt-control-button-content{
    display:none;
}
```